# how to return numbers of field depending of another fields on a db table

Tags: sql, database, linq, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions

i stuck trying to get specific data from my database tables.
my table has the follow structure, 3 columns¨: id(irrelevant for this), area, and typeofdevice

im trying to obtain the areas data ordered  by the amount of typeofdevices of a specific kind, the typeofdevices kind is entered via string parameter in a method. So, for example, in my method the parameter is "computer", and if i have two areas , the first one with 3 computer, and the other with 6 computers  i need to obtain ::   second area name || 6,     and     first area name ||  3

so, pleasea, someone that understand my bad english maze can help me?
thanks.

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want a `where` clause, then aggregation and `order by`:

```
select area, count(*) no_devices
from mytable
where typeofdevice = 'computer'
group by area
order by no_devices desc
```

Comment: ,i will prove and debugg in a minute, but, why the line "order by no_devices desc", dont understand that part

Comment: @HOLDTHEDOOR: you want the result sorted by the number of rows for each area. That's what the `order by` clause does (`no_devices` is an alias for `count(*)`, as you can see in the `select` clause).